# remove illigal char in power automate output from base64ToString

Tags: power-automate

I have created a workflow in power automate where I'm decoding a base64 encoded xml string using the base64ToString() function.
The string is decoded, but a little illegal character is added, and because of that I can't parse the xml.
I get this error later in the flow, when trying to use the functin xml() on the output.

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Convert_string_to_xml' inputs
at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. 
Theprovided value cannot be converted to XML: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, 
position 1.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xml for usage details.'.
```

Why is it added?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a BOM or something. I doubt that it was added by the _decoding_ though, more likely that this was already part of the data when it got _encoded_.

Comment: To work around it, can you not simply find the first < character and parse from there?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Skin. If this is the only instance you can simply use a skip to skip the first character: `skip(base64ToString(outputs('Compose')), 1)`

Comment: That works. Please drop an answer.